# Finding new ways to express the Rieman zeta function

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I would like to ask your opinion about the use that it has to find new ways to express the ζ function.Could it help us to prove or disprove the Riemann hypothesis?I have a proof thay i will be posting soon for a new way to express ζ but first i want your opinion thanks

Comment: Its hard to tell, because RH have so many ways to express Zeta function as sum and as Euler product and so on, assuming you have a valid new way to express Zeta function, that does not necessarily prove RH or give a way to do that, also there are more than dozens of equivalents to RH which do not have Zeta function as part of them yet they are extremely hard, best of luck.

Comment: I am an amateur (thus I am not a professor, nor specialist in any branch of mathematics) studying a lot of mathematics in the past. Last week I tried learn facts about the universality of the Riemann's Zeta function, and also I know some facts from an informative viewpoint about this function and the Riemann Hypothesis. My opinion is that find a new expression (even a new method) being potentially interesting to solve this unsolved problem seems to me currently, in a word: miraculous magic (well were two words).

Answer (score 2):

There is a mathematical question : what can we do and can we prove the RH with all those different formulas for $\zeta(s)$ ?

---

- Of course a proof of the Riemann hypothesis will be based on a new ways to think about $\zeta(s)$ and the primes
- Your new representation of $\zeta(s)$ should not exist for those functions very similar to $\zeta(s)$ but for which the RH fails. So it will have to be based on the Euler product **and** the functional equation.

  In particular, you should check if your new representation and argument in favor of the RH works the same way for $$F(s) =\alpha L(s,\chi_5)+\overline{\alpha} L(s,\overline{\chi_5})$$
  (where $\chi_5$ is the complex [character modulo $5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Modulus_5)) having the same functional equation as $\zeta(s)$ but no Euler product. Automatically it means there are no chances to prove the RH this way, because $F(s)$ has many zeros off the critical line.